# Why is the law of large numbers defined as the probability of a limit rather than the limit of probability?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, limits, probability-limit-theorems, law-of-large-numbers

The law of large numbers states for $X_1,...,X_n$ random variables with finite expectation,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{P}\bigg(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{n}=\mu\bigg) = 1
\end{equation}
where $S_n = X_1+...+X_n$.

I'm struggling to understand the difference between this definition and

\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to\infty} \mathbb{P}\bigg(\frac{S_n}{n}=\mu\bigg) = 1.
\end{equation}

Are they equivilant? Does one imply the other? I know in general that the probability of a limit and the limit of the probability are not equivilant but struggling to understand the reason in this case.

Comment: For a continuous distribution, the probability that the sample mean is exactly equal to the population mean is $0$.  Indeed, the probability of getting any one, exact value is $0$.

Comment: Maybe it will be helpful for you to read about [convergence in probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Convergence_in_probability) and [almost sure convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables#Almost_sure_convergence).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially you are asking why the probability measure is not continuous.  Note that given a sequence of events $A_n$,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\mathbb{P}(A_n)=\mathbb{P}\left(\lim_{n \to \infty }A_n\right)$$

holds if $A_n$ is monotonic, i.e. either $A_1\subseteq A_2\subseteq A_3...$ or $A_1\supseteq A_2\supseteq A_3...$

Without monotonicity, continuity need not hold.

Consider $X_1,X_2,X_3,...$ iid $Bern(1/\pi)$. SLLN tells us

$$P\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i \overset{n\to \infty}{\to}1/\pi\right)=1.$$

However, since $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i\sim Bin(n,1/\pi)$ is integer-valued,

$$P\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i =1/\pi\right)=P\left(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i =n/\pi\right)=0\overset{n\to \infty}{\not\to}1.$$

Comment: So the two statements are equivilant for continuous distributions, but not for discrete distributions. In that case, should we not define the WLLN as $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\to\infty} |S_n/n - \mu|>\epsilon) = 0$ rather than $\lim_{n\to\infty}\mathbb{P}( |S_n/n - \mu|>\epsilon) = 0$?

Comment: @homelessmathaddict My response has nothing to do with continuous distributions; rather, I was referring to continuity of the probability measure (which would allow swapping $\mathbb{P}$ with $\lim$).  The comment from lulu above already mentions how this swapping is not justified for continuous distributions, nor is it justified for discrete distributions (as my answer shows).  Likewise, why do you think we can write WLLN that way?  The events $\{|S_n/n-\mu|>\epsilon\}$ need not be monotonic in $n$.

Comment: If you move the limit inside the probability, then I believe that you get the strong law of large numbers.  So your question boils down to asking what's the difference between the two.

Comment: @Teepeemm Ok, so $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\to\infty}|S_n/n-\mu|>\epsilon),\forall \epsilon>0$ doesn't make sense as $\lim_{n\to\infty}|S_n/n-\mu|$ is always $0$, but I don't think you would immediately get the SLLN (though I see what you mean). I guess it would be $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{n\to\infty}|S_n/n-\mu|=\epsilon), \epsilon=0$ which is then equivilent to SLLN.